# Get a list of all category names and ID's - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, category-tree

How can I get a list of all category names and their ID's from a store on Magento 2.2?

For example something like this

- Clothes 2
- Shirts 5
- T-shirts 7
- T-shirts 8
- Shoes 10
- Sport shoes 12
- ...

It can be in any format and displayed anywhere on the site as long as I can copy it as text. I will disable this functionality after, so I don't mind if it's a quick and dirty way as it's never going on the live site.

Basically I'm trying to find a way to get all product names and ID's without having to individually click through every item in the Magento category tree.

Comment: do you want category name and id, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. A list of ALL category names and ID's from the store in one list.

Comment: check answer I post.

Comment: you got your answer or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Object Manager

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$categoryCollection = $objectManager-
  >get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
 $categories = $categoryCollection->create();
 $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');

   foreach ($categories as $category) {

      echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
   }

  $categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
  $categories = $categoryHelper->getStoreCategories();

  foreach ($categories as $category) {    
   echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
   echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Divya, I got this to work with some editing.
1. On line 2 there shouldn't be space between `$objectManager-` and `>get`
2. The first foreach only lists category names, not ID's. I copied the ID line from lower down on your code.
3. The second half of the code is not needed.

Comment: This is the edited version that worked for me:

`$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
 $categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
  $categories = $categoryCollection->create();
  $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    foreach ($categories as $category) {

       echo $category->getName() . ' / ';
       echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
    }`

Comment: Thnx for response

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create the block at the following location:

> Vendor\Extension\Block\Getcategoryinfo.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;

class Getcategoryinfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCategoryCollection() {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addIsActiveFilter(); 
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Now call that block function into **.phtml** file like this:

```
// get the list of all categories
$categories = $block->getCategoryCollection(); 
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getName() .' '.$category->getId() . '<br />'; 
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I did something wrong, but I'm getting the following error on front end:
'Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in (path to my phtml file)'

Comment: Have you create custom block into your extension? And put the below code into your respective phtml file?